# Leavebuster while playing with bots only

Tags: league-of-legends

If you play a custom league of legends game (hosted by you and passwords and such), but you are only playing with bots, will you get leavebusted if you leave that game? Sometimes I just want to have a 20 minute game for practice, but I would not like to get banned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the support FAQ for [leavebuster](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20030633-leaving-games-the-leaverbuster-faq) you can read:

> **I left a custom/tutorial game and I got a warning that my account may be temporarily suspended? I thought custom games didn't count?**
>
> They don't. This message will appear every time you leave a game, but custom and tutorial games will not earn you a Leaver Level. Leaverbuster only applies to games you have to queue up for = Normal, Ranked, Co-Op Vs AI, Dominion, etc.

So custom game does not count.

Comment: Oh crap I didn't see that, that answered my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Is that why people leave ARAM and dont even care? Does reports in customs game even count ?